# Unable to find LVM volumes: linux kernel options

Tags: lvm, linux-kernel

After kernel recompile, I am not able to boot a linux box.

Error is clear about not finding LVM volumes.

Can you point me to the kernel config options needed to enable boot from LVM2?

I'm pretty sure I forgot something important.

I knew `DM` is needed, but either I didn't enable it or there is something more.

```
grep DM .config
CONFIG_NEED_DMA_MAP_STATE=y
CONFIG_NEED_SG_DMA_LENGTH=y
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA32=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DMA_CONTIGUOUS=y
CONFIG_HAVE_DMA_API_DEBUG=y
# CONFIG_HAVE_GENERIC_DMA_COHERENT is not set
CONFIG_ZONE_DMA=y
CONFIG_DMI=y
CONFIG_ARCH_DMA_ADDR_T_64BIT=y
# CONFIG_ISA_DMA_API is not set
CONFIG_X86_DEV_DMA_OPS=y
CONFIG_DMA_SHARED_BUFFER=y
CONFIG_SCSI_DMA=y
# CONFIG_SCSI_DMX3191D is not set
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM_BUILTIN=y
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_DM=y
# CONFIG_DM_MQ_DEFAULT is not set
# CONFIG_DM_DEBUG is not set
CONFIG_DM_BUFIO=y
# CONFIG_DM_DEBUG_BLOCK_STACK_TRACING is not set
CONFIG_DM_BIO_PRISON=y
CONFIG_DM_PERSISTENT_DATA=y
CONFIG_DM_CRYPT=y
CONFIG_DM_SNAPSHOT=y
CONFIG_DM_THIN_PROVISIONING=y
CONFIG_DM_CACHE=m
CONFIG_DM_CACHE_SMQ=m
CONFIG_DM_CACHE_CLEANER=m
CONFIG_DM_ERA=m
CONFIG_DM_MIRROR=m
CONFIG_DM_LOG_USERSPACE=m
CONFIG_DM_RAID=m
CONFIG_DM_ZERO=m
CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH=m
CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH_QL=m
CONFIG_DM_MULTIPATH_ST=m
CONFIG_DM_DELAY=m
CONFIG_DM_UEVENT=y
CONFIG_DM_FLAKEY=m
CONFIG_DM_VERITY=m
# CONFIG_DM_VERITY_FEC is not set
CONFIG_DM_SWITCH=m
# CONFIG_DM_LOG_WRITES is not set
CONFIG_SERIAL_8250_DMA=y
CONFIG_SENSORS_ADM1021=m
CONFIG_SENSORS_ADM1025=m
CONFIG_SENSORS_ADM1026=m
CONFIG_SENSORS_ADM1029=m
CONFIG_SENSORS_ADM1031=m
CONFIG_SENSORS_ADM9240=m
CONFIG_SENSORS_DME1737=m
CONFIG_HDMI=y
CONFIG_DMADEVICES=y
# CONFIG_DMADEVICES_DEBUG is not set
# DMA Devices
CONFIG_DMA_ENGINE=y
CONFIG_DMA_ACPI=y
# CONFIG_INTEL_IDMA64 is not set
CONFIG_INTEL_IOATDMA=m
# CONFIG_QCOM_HIDMA_MGMT is not set
# CONFIG_QCOM_HIDMA is not set
# CONFIG_DW_DMAC is not set
# CONFIG_DW_DMAC_PCI is not set
# DMA Clients
CONFIG_ASYNC_TX_DMA=y
# CONFIG_DMATEST is not set
CONFIG_DMA_ENGINE_RAID=y
# DMABUF options
# CONFIG_UIO_DMEM_GENIRQ is not set
CONFIG_DMIID=y
CONFIG_DMI_SYSFS=y
CONFIG_DMI_SCAN_MACHINE_NON_EFI_FALLBACK=y
CONFIG_HAVE_C_RECORDMCOUNT=y
# CONFIG_PROVIDE_OHCI1394_DMA_INIT is not set
# CONFIG_DMA_API_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_SECURITY_DMESG_RESTRICT is not set
CONFIG_HAS_DMA=y
```

[image: boot error screen]

Answer (score 2):

Activate the following kernel options:

```
KERNEL
Device Drivers  --->
   Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM)  --->
       <*> Device mapper support
           <*> Crypt target support
           <*> Snapshot target
           <*> Mirror target
       <*> Multipath target
           <*> I/O Path Selector based on the number of in-flight I/Os
           <*> I/O Path Selector based on the service time
```

- Not everything needs to be enabled; some of the options are only needed for LVM2 Snapshots and LVM2 Thin Snapshots, LVM2 Mirrors, LVM2 RAID 0/Stripeset and encryption.

source: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/LVM